# Unit testing FTP in Java (JSch & MockFtpServer)

Tags: java, ftp, mocking, jsch

I'm using JCraft's JSch library for as a FTP client for my program, it's working fine. But I had difficulties creating a mock (MockFtpServer) for unit testing.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.mockftpserver.fake.FakeFtpServer;
import org.mockftpserver.fake.UserAccount;
import org.mockftpserver.fake.filesystem.FileEntry;
import org.mockftpserver.fake.filesystem.FileSystem;
import org.mockftpserver.fake.filesystem.UnixFakeFileSystem;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.Properties;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SFTPManagerTest {

static FakeFtpServer fakeFtpServer;

@BeforeClass
public static void startFTP() throws Exception {
    fakeFtpServer = new FakeFtpServer();
    fakeFtpServer.setServerControlPort(9999);

    FileSystem fileSystem = new UnixFakeFileSystem();
    fileSystem.add(new FileEntry("/data/JFS_HCID_APPLICATION_STATUS_20190109.TXT", "<schema/>"));
    fakeFtpServer.setFileSystem(fileSystem);

    UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount("user", "password", "/");
    fakeFtpServer.addUserAccount(userAccount);
    fakeFtpServer.start();
}

@Test
public void getFileListing() {

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session jschSession = jsch.getSession("user", "localhost", 9999);
        jschSession.setPassword("password");

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        jschSession.setConfig(config);
        jschSession.connect();

        Channel jschChannel = jschSession.openChannel("ftp");
        jschChannel.connect();
        ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) jschChannel;
        Vector v = channel.ls("/data");
        Assert.assertNotNull(v);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@AfterClass
public static void stopFTP() {
    fakeFtpServer.stop();
}
}
```

Dependencies:

- com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55
- org.mockftpserver:MockFtpServer:2.7.1

Output: it always stuck/stall during executing test method, not finishing. When stuck/stalling I could access the MockFtpServer with WinSCP or FTP CLI. From the log it seems the command from JSch not recognized.

```
2019-02-18 17:54:15,996 INFO  [Thread-0] org.mockftpserver.core.server.AbstractFtpServer: Connection accepted from host /127.0.0.1
2019-02-18 17:54:16,002 INFO  [Thread-6] org.mockftpserver.core.command.AbstractTrackingCommandHandler: Sending reply [220 Service ready for new user. (MockFtpServer 2.7.1; see http://mockftpserver.sourceforge.net)]
2019-02-18 17:54:16,004 INFO  [Thread-6] org.mockftpserver.core.session.DefaultSession: Received command: [SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54]
2019-02-18 17:54:16,004 WARN  [Thread-6] org.mockftpserver.core.command.UnsupportedCommandHandler: No CommandHandler is defined for command [SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54]
2019-02-18 17:54:16,005 INFO  [Thread-6] org.mockftpserver.core.command.AbstractTrackingCommandHandler: Sending reply [502 Command not implemented: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54.]
```

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSch is an SSH/**SFTP** library. You cannot use an **FTP** server to test it. You need to use an **SFTP** server. FTP and SFTP are two completely unrelated and different protocols.